# PlayFramework - Running functional test with json rendering

Tags: java, json, playframework

I'm trying to run this functional test

```
    public class JsonRenderTest extends FunctionalTest {    
        @Before
        public void setup() {
            Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
            Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");
        }

        @Test
        public void testThatJsonRenderingWorks() {
            Response response = GET("/recipe/1");
            assertIsOk(response);
        }
     }
```

The action answering this call is this

```
    public static void showRecipe(Long id){
        Recipe recipe = Recipe.findById(id);
        notFoundIfNull(recipe);
        renderJSON(recipe);
    }
```

When I run the test in firefox using the TestRunner at http://localhost:8080/@tests 
I get this error message:

> Failure, Response status  expected:<200> but was:<404>

Now if I run this url http://localhost:8080/recipe/1 in a browser, I get the json responce I'm expecting wich is a json representation of my recipe object.

There is of course a recipe in the database with id 1.

Now here is my question. Why is the test failing when the browser is not. I tryed this in Chrome, IE and FF with the same result.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.
Thanks

-Alain

Comment: what version of play are u using? 

You should not assume the entity will have id = 1 when loaded from the Fixtures.

Try do a find("byName") or some other property your Recipe object has, and then build the URL using that object id.

Comment: Thanks Marco. I'm using Play-1.2.3. I will try your suggestion and report back

Comment: Tried your suggestion and there is no difference.

Comment: Did you change the default port? I can see you are using 8080 instead of 9000

Answer (score 1):

Thanks eveyone.
Ok I found the answer.
It appears that my test was running before the fixture data was fully loaded. 
I was running my tests against a local MySql database.
When I removed the call

```
Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
```

The test was running fine.

To fix the problem I am now running my test against a mem database with this in the application.conf file

```
%test.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper method to add content type to your request

```
public Request jsonRequest(Request request) {
    request.contentType = "application/json";
    request.format = "json";
    return request;

}
```

Then your test become

```
    @Test
    public void testThatJsonRenderingWorks() {
        Response response = GET(jsonRequest(newRequest)), "/recipe/1");
        assertIsOk(response);
    }
 }
```

You can also you WS classes to do real http tests insted.